# Cerrar una página desde un popup con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web y desde una página abro un pop-up. Desde ese pop-up me abre otra página y quiero que se cierre la anterior. Ya he probado con `self.close()` y con `window.close()` pero soy incapaz de cerrar la página desde el pop-up.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para tener acceso a la ventana original tienes que usar la propiedad `window.opener` ([aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) tienes la documentación)

Y este es código con el que la cerrarías:

```
window.opener.close()
```

Comment: Recomiendo esta documentación en español y de una fuente mas respetable que w3schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

Comment: Gracias @CarlosMuñoz, no sé si será mas respetable u oficioso, yo suelo usar w3schools para referencia rápida y hasta ahora no me ha fallado,  me gusta la información que proporciona sobre el soporte en los diferentes navegadores. Como documentación creo que tu enlace es mas adecuado así que he editado la respuesta y lo he cambiado

Comment: Te recomiendo esto: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Hola @amamista, ¿probaste `windows.opener`? ¿te funcionó? Estaría bien que si te fue útil esta respuesta (o la otra) la marcaras como aceptada para ayudas al resto de usuarios. O si necesitas mas ayuda, dínoslo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

`window.close()` puede ser llamada únicamente desde la pagina que ejecuto `window.open()`. Como lo comenta rsciriano, puede realizarse con

> [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) Devuelve una referencia de, la ventana que abrió la
>   ventana actuál.

```
if (window.opener != indexWin) {
  referToTop(window.opener);
}
```

Comment: Jorgesys, podrías ser mas explicito donde pongo ese if ese codigo pertence a que lenguaje ya que en el front se usa muchos